# Ubuntu broken machine (backup mysql via FTP)

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, backup

I cannot access my virtual machine (ubuntu 14.04). The only way to connnect is via the FTP. I really need to backup all mysql databases from there. Is this possible to just copy the whole mysql directory to the new machine? Will it work?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your mysql server running? Is it reachable remotely, or does it only listen locally? In the first case, you can reach your mysql server and backup from the network with mysql tools. Filesystem backup ``might`` work if there is no write update during the process. Which solution of virtualisation do you use? Do you have access to the host?

Answer (score 1):

yes. it will work.

```
copy:
/var/lib/mysql/* 
/etc/mysql/*
```

then you can create another one VM with mysql and copy back the data.

Comment: Be careful though. If there are unflushed pages in the buffer pool you'll end up with corrupted tablespace.